# Grunt build successful but getting client error [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, build, minify, angular-fullstack

I have successfully created the project and everything is working as expected and now we want to deploy it to production.

Below are generator config:

generator-angular-fullstack | 3.0.0-rc4
Node | v6.4.0
npm | 3.10.7
Operating System | OS X 10

Transpiler | Javascript
Markup | HTML
CSS | CSS
Router | ui-router
Client Tests | Mocha
DB | MongoDB
Auth | Y

```
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

    Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
    Minified 199 images (saved 1.89 MB)

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2017-01-11 17:15:12 UTC+5:30)
    loading tasks                   332ms  ▇ 2%
    loading grunt-contrib-imagemin  571ms  ▇ 3%
    imagemin:dist                   16.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 95%
    Total 17.5s

    Running "newer:babel:client" (newer) task

    Running "babel:client" (babel) task

    Running "newer-postrun:babel:client:1:/Users/abhijitroy/Documents/Working/tmp/autocentric2/node_modules/grunt-newer/.cache" (newer-postrun) task

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2017-01-11 17:15:12 UTC+5:30)
    loading tasks        331ms  ▇ 1%
    loading grunt-babel  841ms  ▇▇ 4%
    babel:client         20.8s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 94%
    Total 22.1s[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "client/app/main/js/angular-material.min.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
    [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "client/app/main/js/materialize.min.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (83 files)

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (24 files)

Running "wiredep:client" (wiredep) task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

Running "postcss:dist" (postcss) task

Running "ngtemplates:main" (ngtemplates) task
File .tmp/templates.js created.
Added .tmp/templates.js to <!-- build:js app/app.js -->

Running "ngtemplates:tmp" (ngtemplates) task
>> No templates found
File .tmp/tmp-templates.js created.
Added .tmp/tmp-templates.js to <!-- build:js app/app.js -->

Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File .tmp/concat/app/vendor.css created.
File .tmp/concat/app/app.css created.
File .tmp/concat/app/vendor.js created.
File .tmp/concat/app/app.js created.

Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
>> 2 files successfully generated.

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
Created 152 directories, copied 823 files

Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/client/index.html to update script refs
✔ bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js

Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
>> Ignoring remote @import of "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600" as no callback given.,Ignoring remote @import of "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" as no callback given.,Unexpected '}' in '.container{}}@media only screen '. Ignoring.
>> 2 files created. 859.79 kB → 769.68 kB

Running "uglify:generated" (uglify) task
>> 2 files created.

Running "filerev:dist" (filerev) task
Revved 216 files

Running "usemin:html" (usemin) task
Replaced 1 reference to assets

Running "usemin:css" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "usemin:js" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-01-11 17:15:11 UTC+5:30)
concurrent:dist              22.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
ngAnnotate:dist               3.6s  ▇ 2%
loading grunt-google-cdn      2.3s  ▇ 1%
cdnify:dist                     8s  ▇▇ 4%
cssmin:generated              3.1s  ▇ 2%
uglify:generated          2m 39.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 78%
```

I am getting below error on browser:

> vendor.a8d7977e.js:3 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
>   provider: AuthProvider <- Auth
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthProvider%20%3C-%20Auth
>           at vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>           at vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>           at Object.d [as get] (vendor.a8d7977e.js:4)
>           at vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>           at d (vendor.a8d7977e.js:4)
>           at Object.e [as invoke] (vendor.a8d7977e.js:4)
>           at vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>           at f (vendor.a8d7977e.js:3)
>           at bb (vendor.a8d7977e.js:4)
>           at h (vendor.a8d7977e.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>       (anonymous) @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       d @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       (anonymous) @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       d @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       e @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       (anonymous) @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       f @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>       bb @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:4
>       h @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>       ga @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>       fa @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:3
>       (anonymous) @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:8
>       j @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:2
>       fireWith @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:2
>       ready @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:2
>       g @ vendor.a8d7977e.js:1

Request for help so that we can proceed with production deployment.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `grunt serve` works fine?

Comment: Yes, grunt serve works fine